# ASP.NET MVC UI Template: How to mix an IList Model property with EditorFor( m => m.subModel)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, editorfor, ui-helper

Say you have this:

```
public class ShoppingCart {
    public IList<CartItem> cartItems {get; set; }
}
```

And you do this to render the class:

```
<%= EditorFor( m => m.ShoppingCart, "ShoppingCart") %>
```

How would you do the EditorFor( ??, "CartItem") in the ShoppingCart.ascx?  I would think it would look something like this:

```
<% foreach( CartItem myCartItem in m.cartItems) { 
     %><%= EditorFor( ??, "CartItem")
%><% } %>
```

The idea here of course is to use a UI template for an entire class, not just a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% for (int count = 0; count < Model.cartItems.Count; count++ )
   {                                              %><%= 
      Html.EditorFor(m => m.cartItems[count])      %><%
   } 
%>
```

Creates form names like:

```
name="cartItems[0].Name"
name="cartItems[1].Name"
name="cartItems[2].Name"
```

Which bind back to the original List view model

Answer (score 1):

If the model of your ShoppingCart.ascx is the ShoppingCart class, then you should be able to do

```
<% foreach (CartItem myCartItem in m.cartItems) { %>
    <%= EditorFor(m => myCartItem, "CartItem") %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: MVC will take
<input id="mylist[0].Name" />
<input id="mylist[0].Address" />
<input id="mylist[1].Name" />
<input id="mylist[1].Address" />
And map them to IList<Customer> mylist.
That said, do you create a UI template for Customer, pass an index in the ViewData so it knows which iteration of the IList we are on, and how would you format the id="" for the template?  I guess we stop using UI templates to get IList to work?

Comment: Scott Guthrie talked about MVC 2 RC handing array or collection indexes in EditorFor(m => m.ArrayOfItems[i]).  Any idea how to get this to work with a List so that the post maps back to the original object?